# .Count() on the view is actually retrieving all the record from the database, and unnecessary SQL batch is generated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following tables :-

[image]

And the following action method:-

```
 public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(groupRepository.AllIncluding(group => group.SecurityRoles));
        }
```

And the following repository:-

```
 public IQueryable<Group> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Group, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<Group> query = context.Groups;
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
            return query;
        }
```

The generate SQL (usig the SQL server profiler) when navigating to the action method is:; Two SQL batches & And one RPC. As follow:-

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[GroupID] AS [GroupID], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[SecurityRoleID] AS [SecurityRoleID], 
[Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
[Project1].[Description1] AS [Description1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[GroupID] AS [GroupID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Join1].[SecurityRoleID1] AS [SecurityRoleID], 
    [Join1].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Join1].[Description] AS [Description1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join1].[SecurityRoleID2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Groups] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[SecurityRoleID] AS [SecurityRoleID2], [Extent2].[GroupID] AS [GroupID], [Extent3].[SecurityRoleID] AS [SecurityRoleID1], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent3].[Description] AS [Description]
        FROM  [dbo].[SecurityRoleGroups] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRoles] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[SecurityRoleID] = [Extent2].[SecurityRoleID] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[GroupID] = [Join1].[GroupID]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[GroupID] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC



SELECT 
[Project1].[GroupID] AS [GroupID], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[SecurityRoleID] AS [SecurityRoleID], 
[Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
[Project1].[Description1] AS [Description1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[GroupID] AS [GroupID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Join1].[SecurityRoleID1] AS [SecurityRoleID], 
    [Join1].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Join1].[Description] AS [Description1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join1].[SecurityRoleID2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Groups] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[SecurityRoleID] AS [SecurityRoleID2], [Extent2].[GroupID] AS [GroupID], [Extent3].[SecurityRoleID] AS [SecurityRoleID1], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent3].[Description] AS [Description]
        FROM  [dbo].[SecurityRoleGroups] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRoles] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[SecurityRoleID] = [Extent2].[SecurityRoleID] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[GroupID] = [Join1].[GroupID]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[GroupID] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC



exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[GroupID] AS [GroupID], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
FROM [dbo].[UserGroups] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[GroupID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1
```

But I have the following questions:-

1. Why there are two SQL batches being generated.
2. When I have issued a

   @(item.UserGroups == null ? "None" : item.UserGroups.Count.ToString())

On the view it will retrieve all the records from the table , instead of just counting the record inside the database and then return the count number.

3. Why in the Scaffolding generated code, it will only pass the SecurityRole navigation property and ignored the UserGroups navigation property?

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass your model to view as `List` instead of `IQueryable`:

```
return View(groupRepository.AllIncluding(group => group.SecurityRoles).ToList());
```

Comment: That doesn't change a anything. The query will materialize down the line regardless where it is enumerated over and it does not affect how the query is generated.

Comment: you are right assigning a Tolist() will only execute one SQL batch. and i have eager loaded the Group.UserGroup property so now it will only execute one SQL batch. this means that if i do not have a .Tolist() then whenever there is a loop over the object on the view, it will reach the database regardless of the results of the previouse queires